# How to feed a modified value back into the modification loop in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of string **values** (Telegram posts). Many of those individual values include string **patterns** I want to remove (JSON formatting).

An example string value would be, "['Оппозиционный российский политик Алесей Навальный впал в кому. Его соратники считают, что его отравили.\n\nСейчас Навальный находится в омской больнице скорой медицинской помощи №\u202f1. Посетителей к нему не пускают. ', {'type': 'bold', 'text': 'Очень странные дела.'}, '']"

Examples seen here of the string patterns I want to remove include,

- \n
- u202f1
- ', {'type': 'bold', 'text':
- }, ''

I have a list of the string patterns I want to remove, in a xslx spreadsheet.

For just a few corrections I would manually get there using Python's **replace** function. In this case, for a single string value I want to loop through the 'corrections list' and replace against each of these (replacing with blank, ie "").

But each time the string is subject to a replace action it then needs to be **fed into the next replace action** - unsure how to do this?

I suspect maybe a '**while True**' loop, but not sure how to craft it.

This is where I am with my code playing ...

```
# GET THE 'CORRECTIONS' TO FIND & REPLACE (WITH BLANK) IN THE TARGET STRING (TELEGRAM POST)

def load_corrections(filepath): 
                
                corrections = []
                
                wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)
                ws = wb.active
                
                rows = list(ws.rows) # convert the openpyxl generator object into a list
                
                for row in rows[1:]: # skip the heading
                                
                                corrections.append(row[0].value)
                                

                return corrections

# FUNCTION TO TAKE 'DIRTY' STRING VALUE, SUBJECT TO LIST OF 'CORRECTIONS', RETURN CLEAN STRING VALUE

def clean_message_text(dirty_text): 
                
                corrections_data = load_corrections(corrections_filepath) # get the list of 'corrections'
                                
                for c in corrections_data:
                                clean_text = dirty_text.replace(c[0], "")

                                # ⬆⬆⬆⬆⬆⬆⬆⬆⬆⬆ this is the issue - I need this new clean_text to be fed back into the loop to be subject to the next correction list

                                
                return clean_text
```

Hope that all makes sense. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good, you only need to apply one after the other. No need for a clean text variable, calling a function with a string generates a new object (like call-by-value if you know the term, read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-python-call-by-reference-or-call-by-value/)).

```
def clean_message_text(dirty_text):
    corrections_data = load_corrections(corrections_filepath) 
    for c in corrections_data:
        dirty_text = dirty_text.replace(c, "") # note that you probably need to replace c and not c[0]?
    return dirty_text
```

P.S.: Maybe you want to rename `dirty_text` to something like `message` to demonstrate that the string is not dirty at the end.